# How do I stop a forward slash from being displayed at the end of a URL

Tags: url

I am running an Apache 2.4 webserver.

I have a file: http://192.168.0.12/test/index.html

Right now, if I access this file, it displays this in the address bar:

http://192.168.0.12/test/

All I want, is for it to instead display this:

http://192.168.0.12/test

**Edit:** I decided to get around the problem by instead storing everything I needed from the /test/ directory in the /test-content/ directory, and changing the /test/index.html file to just /test.html

Comment: Your programming Language?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .htaccess file and add the below rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test$ /test1/ [L]
```

Comment: If I go to http://192.168.0.12/test it still redirects to http://192.168.0.12/test/

Comment: The web server is making the redirect you can this rename test directory to test1 and then place the below rule in .htaccess                      
                  RewriteEngine On
                  RewriteRule ^test$ /test1/ [L]